# removing a list from list

Tags: r, list

I have a large list containing multiple lists. Some of these sub-lists are null so I want to remove them from the large list. I am trying the following but it seems that it is not working properly:

```
dat = lapply(dat, function(x){if(all(is.na(x)) == TRUE){list.remove(dat, 'x')}})
```

Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you share an example of your list?

Answer (score 1):

An option if the `list` element is `NULL` is `Filter`

```
lapply(lst1, function(lst2) Filter(Negate(is.null), lst2))
```

Or with `length`

```
lapply(lst1, function(lst2) Filter(length, lst2))
```

and if it is the `NA` elements

```
lapply(lst1, function(lst2) Filter(function(x) any(!is.na(x)), lst2))
```

NOTE: The OP mentioned `list` off `list`s

Answer (score 1):

Simple subsetting:

```
L <- list(1, 2, NULL)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2
#
#[[3]]
#NULL

L <- L[lengths(L) > 0]
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the previous answers suggested, I recommend you transfer the list to as pandas data frame if your list is too complicate for better visualization.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

Then you can use a wide range of functions in pandas. For example, you can do this:

```
df.dropna() # drop all rows with missing data
```

Or you can do

```
df[df.x.notnull()] # drop rows which have null values in the x column
```